# out of bound error i have changed this code from array to array list now it is giving bound error?

Tags: java

This whole project previously had array in package products in class produt list now i am using Array list now in the package main in the Swi test it is giving error that it cannot be converted to Productlist from product. i think there is problem with this part too. i think there is something wrong with the productlist.

now it is giving an out of bound error

Comment: the `storeProduct` method in the class `SwiTest` expects a `ProductList` as an argument, but you are trying to pass a `Product` into that method.

Comment: tl;dr But is should probably be: `public void storeProduct(Product p) {...}`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While it's nice to see the code, you've provided over 500 lines of code, almost all of which will be irrelevant to the issue. It's a really good idea to reduce the problem as far as you possibly can, to a [mcve]. That will often help you fix the problem yourself - but when it doesn't, the question you can then post will be far better.

Comment: Can you provide more code related to this issue, please? If previously your code snippet was too large, then now it has a very few information.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void storeProduct(Product p) {
        products.addProd(p);
}
```

Update your SwiTest Function like above.

Also, the naming convention that you followed is not up to the standard.
Like, package name and variable name should start with small letters and follow the camelCase.

Answer (score 0):

The add function you used gets ProductList as parameter. But you passed a new Product. First you need to change storeProduct argument ProductList to Product, and then you need to use addProd method instead of add inside of the storeProduct method.

public void add(ProductList prods)

public void addProd(Product prod)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    SwiTest shop = new SwiTest("My Online Shop"); 

    // prepare list of products
    ProductList selectedProductList = new ProductList();
    selectedProductList.addProd(new Product("CD Spieler", new Price(new Euro(315,0),19),10));
    selectedProductList.addProd(new Product("CD Miles Davis: Kind of Blue", new Price(new Euro(10,50),19),5));        
    selectedProductList.addProd(new Product("Wasserkocher", new Price(new Euro(80,98),19),5));                
    selectedProductList.addProd(new Product("Champagner Taittinger", new Price(new Euro(42,81),19),2));  
    selectedProductList.addProd(new Product("Korkenzieher", new Price(new Euro(5,21),7),10));
    selectedProductList.addProd(new Product("Italienische Nudeln 500g", new Price(new Euro(11,21),7),5));

    // assign list of products to storeProduct
    shop.storeProduct (selectedProductList);       

    // your others code         
}
```